# Jquery - Can't get class to work in dynamically added li element

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a select list input that allow user to select multiple item. Upon selection, it will **dynamically** create a new li item in my ordered list as in the HTML code below.

**HTML**

```
<ol class="asmList3" id="multiol">
   <li rel="multioption1" class="asmListItem2" style="height: 20px; ">
      <span class="asmListItemLabel2">Acrylic</span>
      <a href="#" class="liRemoveItem">X</a>
   </li>
</ol>
```

**Script**

```
$('.liRemoveItem').click(function(){
   alert("X is clicked");
   //remove child li
});
```

Supposely on clicking on the `X` which has the class `liRemoveItem`, I wish to remove the child li but the class is not even working for a simple alert. I think it is because the child li was created dynamically.

If the li was added in the HTML when loaded and not dynamically created, the class `liRemoveItem` works. Can someone please give me a hint as to what I did wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the **[jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method

Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and **in the future.**

```
   $('.liRemoveItem').live("click",function(){    
      alert("X is clicked");    //remove child li 
   });
```

The `.live()` method is able to affect elements that have **not yet been added** to the `DOM` through the use of event delegation: a handler bound to an ancestor element is responsible for events that are triggered on its descendants. The handler passed to `.live()` is **never bound to an element**; instead, `.live()` binds a **special handler** to the **root** of the DOM tree

Comment: It works! Thank you, now I know how to use the live.() function.

Comment: jQuery live was  deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9

Answer (score 3):

Try using this

```
$('.liRemoveItem').live('click', function() {
   alert("X is clicked");
           //remove child li

});
```